# Add pagination to recent posts shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination

I've created a shortcode that displays my recent posts but I want to have the option to add pagination. I'm trying to use the pagination attribute. Please see my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
add_shortcode( 'list_recent_posts', 'list_recent_posts' );
function list_recent_posts( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    // define attributes and their defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'posts' => 4,
        'category' => '',
        'ptype' => '',
        'class' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $class = $atts['class'];

    // define query parameters based on attributes
    $options = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'post_type' => $ptype,
        'category_name' => $category
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $options );
    // run the loop based on the query
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

<ul class="media recent-posts <?php echo $class; ?>">

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="media-listitem">

<?php
  if(has_post_thumbnail()):
    ?><a class="pull-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail');
        }
      ?> 
    </div>
  </a>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>


<?php
  if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <div class="media-content marginlft-90">
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="media-content">
<?php endif; ?>


                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('%s', 'heels'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                        </div>
                </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


</ul>
<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post:

```
if ( ! function_exists('vpsa_posts_shortcode') ) {
        function vpsa_posts_shortcode( $atts ){

            $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                            'per_page'  =>      2,  
                            'order'     =>  'DESC',
                            'orderby'   =>  'date'
                    ), $atts );

            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $args = array(
                'post_type'         =>  'post',
                'posts_per_page'    =>  $atts["per_page"], 
                'order'             =>  $atts["order"],
                'orderby'           =>  $atts["orderby"],
                'paged'             =>  $paged
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if($query->have_posts()) : $output;

                        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

                            $output .= '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" class="' . implode(' ', get_post_class()) . '">';

                                $output .= '<h4 class="post-title"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title('','',false) . '">' . the_title('','',false) . '</a></span></h4>';

                                $output .= '<div class="row">';

                                    $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">'; 

                                        $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title('','',false) . '">';

                                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                                                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_id(), 'featured', array('class' => 'img-responsive aligncenter'));

                                            } else {

                                               $output .= '<img class="img-responsive aligncenter" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/not-available.png" alt="Not Available" height="150" width="200" />';                                           

                                            }

                                        $output .= '</a>';

                                    $output .= '</div>';

                                    $output .= '<div class="col-md-9">';

                                        $output .= get_the_excerpt();

                                        $output .= '<span class="post-permalink"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title('','',false) . '">Read More</a></span>';

                                    $output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= '<div class="post-info">';

                                    $output .= '<ul>';

                                        $output .= '<li>Posted: ' . get_the_time("F j, Y") . '</li>';

                                        $output .= '<li>By: ' . get_the_author() . '</li>';

                                        $output .= '<li>Categories: ' . get_the_category_list(", ") . '</li>';

                                    $output .= '</ul>';

                                $output .= '</div>';

                            $output .= '</article>';

                        endwhile;global $wp_query;
    $args_pagi = array(
            'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $paged
            );
                        $output .= '<div class="post-nav">';
                            $output .= paginate_links( $args_pagi);

                        //    $output .= '<div class="next-page">' . get_next_posts_link( "Older Entries »", 3 ) . '</div>';

                        $output .= '</div>';

                    else:

                        $output .= '<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>';

                    endif;

                wp_reset_postdata();

                return $output;
        }
    }

    add_shortcode('vpsa_posts', 'vpsa_posts_shortcode');
```

Comment: Hello, I need to ask, I tested your code and it works, but do you have the CSS for it?